# ajax callback not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

i cannot seem to get a callback to work from this but it gets a response its a simple test. anyone know why it dosnt do as i want

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("button").click(function() {
        var msg = $("#txt").val();
        $.post(
            "http://localhost/bot.php",
            {msg: msg},
            function(data,status) {
                $("p").text(data);
            }
        );
    });
});
</script>
```

The PHP, and could anyone suggest a good JavaScript tool to help me find errors?

```
<?php

class ai
{
    private $msg;

    public function __construct($msg)
    {
        $this->msg = $msg;
    }

    public function respond()
    {
        switch($this->msg)
        {
            case "hi":
                echo "Hello Mr Brown How are You";
                break;
            case "fine":
                echo "Good to hear Did you know Zanda hard Coded me?";
                break;
            case "im fine":
                echo "Good to hear Did you know Zanda hard Coded me?";
                break;
            default:
                echo "??????????????????????????????" .
                     "That means i was extra rush prototype.......i cant answer that";
        }
    }
}

$talk = new ai($_POST['msg']);
$talk->respond();

?>


<div class="box">
<p>text</p>
<textarea id="txt"></textarea>
<button>click</button>
</div>
```

there is the html made it as short as can be

Comment: if you examine the ajax request in firebug what does it say? do you get a 404? a response?

Comment: use a chrome browser and Control+Shift+J and there are code debugging and network trace tools built in

Comment: "good js tool to help me find errors" ; the console would be a good start, get chrome or download firebug in firefox. Post your HTML if you can, and have you included the jQuery library?

Comment: on either ie or chrome (preferable), press f12.  go to the console tab and that should lead you to the error

Comment: i did check the console in firefox but it says http:200 ok

Comment: but in chrome it says  " XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/bot.php. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

Comment: i think that would be a strange msg seeing as both files are on my local server

Comment: provide a demo or more information please

Comment: firefox's fire bug says the request is ok but no response from the server.......yes if i explicitly call the bot.php it will give me the default msg

Comment: its saying the origin is null i think the answer lies in there

Comment: @alex_zander try adding data type .. see answer below

Comment: I have also added the reason for null that you are getting

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Origin+null+is+not+allowed+by+Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: If there's a same-origin-policy violation then the ajax request needs to be done with `dataType: 'jsonp'`, not regular JSON.

Comment: Check out http://pastebin.com/7wfyAidG it works perfectly on my local server. Also, see how ajax request is distinguished?

Comment: @Prasanth.I realized with the exception of your check our code was doing the same thing. then it must have been another reason mine wasnt working. Thanks@everybody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it is due to the Same Origin Policy and from the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)

> The port number is kept separately by the browser. Any call to the setter, including document.domain = document.domain causes the port number to be overwritten with null. Therefore one can not make company.com:8080 talk to company.com by only setting document.domain = "company.com" in the first. It has to be set in both so that port numbers are both null.

So that is the reason you are getting null as you said in your responses

Try adding `datatype:"jsonp"`. It shoudl work like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("button").click(function() {
        var msg = $("#txt").val();
        $.post(
            "http://localhost/bot.php",
            {msg: msg},
            function(data,status) {
                $("p").text(data);
            },
            dataType:"jsonp"
        );
    });
});
```

Further reading [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

Hope that helps.

Comment: When i read your comment i realized my answer. Which is exactly as the pc said. i Was loading the html file from my desktop and the php from my server. So as you said it would make the html have a origin of null it being overritten by my server.

Answer (score 1):

Something to try here too is to change your `$.post` for `$.ajax` so you can specify an error callback. `$.get`, `$.post` etc are just shorthands for `$.ajax` anyhow. Try something like this:

```
("button").click(function() {
    var msg = $("#txt").val();
    $.ajax(
        url: "http://localhost/bot.php",
        data: {msg: msg},
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data,status) {
            console.log(data, "returned with status:", status);
        },
        error: function(obj, status, error){
            console.log("Error!", obj, status, error);
        }
    );
});
```

Just because you're getting a `200` response doesn't mean everything's working correctly. All that's saying is that the POST was successful. You need to check the response text to see if any errors are being returned.

EDIT: added in `dataType: 'jsonp'` to request.

Comment: Thank you very much could not have solved this without your help